# Creating multiselect checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring, jsp

I have a select statement where I can select one value at a time , I am trying to create a checkbox for multi-select. My dropdown values are coming from the backend. I cannot use any bootstrap plugin. Below is the code, is there anyway to achieve this with little modification to the code. Any help will be appreciated.

```js
 
function selectMultiple(studentList) {
  for (var i = 0; i < studentList.length; i++) {
    let studentVal = studentList[i];
    $("#student").append('<option value="' + studentVal + '">' + studentVal + '</option>');
  }
}

//studentlist coming from backend
var studentList = ['A', 'B', 'C'];

selectMultiple(studentList);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="test">
      <select id="student">
        <option selected="selected" value="default">select here</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Where is the HTML for your checkbox?

Comment: Minimal change: `<select multiple id="student">`

Comment: Krishna td with id test is the HTML code

Comment: @user10806781 Krishna is referring to your request for "*create a checkbox for multi-select*".   There's no "checkbox for multi-select" in your HTML, just a `<select>` - if you're looking to creating a drop down with checkboxes, then that's not exactly a one-liner and you'll be better off using a jquery plugin.

Comment: freedomn, using multiple will work but it wont give me checkboxes, how can i get checkboxes uisng jquery plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use `<ul>` tag and modify your css so it just look like `drop-down` list , also in below code I have used `.one("click",function()..` so that there will not be multiple `append`.

```js
$("#s1").one("click",function(){

  for (var i = 0; i < studentList.length; i++) {
    let studentVal = studentList[i];
    $("#student").append('<li value="' + studentVal + '">' +'<input type="checkbox">'+ studentVal + '</li>');
  }

});



//studentlist coming from backend
var studentList = ['A', 'B', 'C'];
```

```css
ul li:hover, ul li:focus {
 color:red;
}

li{
list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="test">
      <ul id="student">
        <li id="s1" selected="selected" value="default">Select here</li>
      </ul>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this
Put those details which you get from backend, into an array(like assosiative array) and then pass it to the frontend. Then access the array elements at frontend.
Ex: " >

Answer (score 0):

Try and change your select to this: `<select id="student" multiple>`
You then should be able to hold down the ctrl button and select multiple values

Comment: anyother way to get checkboxes

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code snippet for having checkboxes inside a drop down.

```css
.multipleSelect {
  width: 130px;
}

.selectBox {
  position: relative;
}

.selectBox select {
  width: auto;
}

.selectionBox {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

#multipleCheckbox {
  display: none;
  border: 1px solid;
}

#multipleCheckbox label {
  display: block;
}

#multipleCheckbox label:hover {
  background-color: #42ecf5;
}
```

```html
<div class="multipleSelect">
  <div class="selectBox" onclick="showMultipleCheckbox()">
    <select>
      <option>Select a checkbox</option>
    </select>
    <div class="selectionBox"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="multipleCheckbox">
    <label for="one">
        <input type="checkbox" id="one" />Check box1</label>
    <label for="two">
        <input type="checkbox" id="two" />Check box2</label>
    <label for="three">
        <input type="checkbox" id="three" />Check box3</label>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
  var selectTagOpen = false;

  function showMultipleCheckbox() {
    var checkboxes = document.getElementById("multipleCheckbox");
    if (!selectTagOpen) {
      checkboxes.style.display = "block";
      selectTagOpen = true;
    } else {
      checkboxes.style.display = "none";
      selectTagOpen = false;
    }
  }
</script>
```